# Can I declare TypeScript interfaces in a separated file and use it without ever importing it?

Tags: typescript

Right now I have to either declare interface right where I use it or `import {ISomeInterface} from './somePlace'`. Is there a way to just declare interfaces in `something.interface.ts` files and use those interfaces without importing them?

E.g. i'm not importing `@types/node` to use interfaces declared in the `@types/node`, right? I'd like to do it with custom interfaces too.

Comment: Why is importing an issue for you? Are you doing it manually? I recommend using a different / configuring your editor / IDE to import for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the types globally. If you declare a `ts` or `d.ts` file, that does not export anything and **does not use any `import` statement** then your file will be treated add adding to the global scope. You can use import types if you need to access types from modules, using `import('moduleName').Type`.

You could also use `declare global` inside a file that does contain imports:

```
import { Type } from 'module'
declare global {
    interface GlobalInterface {
        o: Type 
    }
}
```